# Adding data to two different tables from one form using spring and JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am trying to add data to two different tables from one form using JPA and Spring. I was able to figure out how to do it by hard-coding the latitude and longitude data into the service class method for one of the tables; however, I am unsure how to enable the user to input the data himself for the latitude and longitude, which are in the second table from the same form.

The addBreweries.jsp form code is:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/Assignment2/breweries/addBrewery" modelAttribute="brewerie">

    <table>

        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            <td style="color:red"><form:errors path="name"/> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="address1">Address 1</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="address1" /></td>
            <td style="color:red"><form:errors path="address1"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="address2">Address 2</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="address2"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"><form:errors path="address2"/> </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="city">City</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="city"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"><form:errors path="city"/> </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="state">State</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="state"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"><form:errors path="state"/> </td>

        </tr>
           <tr>
            <td><form:label path="code">Code</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="code"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"><form:errors path="code"/> </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="country">Country</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="country"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="country"/> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="phone">Phone Number</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="phone"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="phone"/> </td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td><form:label path="website">Website</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="website"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"><form:errors path="website"/> </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="description">Description</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="description"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="description"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="addUser">Add User</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="addUser"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="addUser"/> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="creditLimit">Credit Limit</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="creditLimit"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="creditLimit"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="email">Email</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="email"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="email"/> </td>
        </tr>



        <tr>

            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

The code for the controller is:

```
 @PostMapping("/addBrewery")
public ModelAndView addAnAgent(@ModelAttribute("brewerie") Breweries brewerie) {
Date date = new Date();
    brewerie.setLastMod(date);

    service.addAnBreweries(brewerie);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/breweries");

}
```

The service class method I'm using is:

```
 public void addAnBreweries(Breweries brewerie) {
    EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEMF().createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction();
    Date date = new Date();
    brewerie.setLastMod(date);
    try {
        trans.begin();
        em.persist(brewerie);
        trans.commit();

        BreweriesGeocode bg = new BreweriesGeocode();
        bg.setBreweryId((Integer) brewerie.getId());
        bg.setLongitude(-97);
        bg.setLatitude(30);
         trans.begin();
        em.persist(bg);
        trans.commit();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

The Breweries.java class is:

```
package brewery.src.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.SecondaryTable;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author k00203657
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "breweries")

@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findAll", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findById", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByName", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByAddress1", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.address1 = :address1"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByAddress2", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.address2 = :address2"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByCity", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.city = :city"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByState", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.state = :state"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByCode", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.code = :code"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByCountry", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.country = :country"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByPhone", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.phone = :phone"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByWebsite", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.website = :website"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByImage", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.image = :image"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByAddUser", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.addUser = :addUser"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByLastMod", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.lastMod = :lastMod"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByCreditLimit", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.creditLimit = :creditLimit"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByEmail", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.email = :email")})
public class Breweries implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "address1")
private String address1;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "address2")
private String address2;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "city")
private String city;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "state")
private String state;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 25)
@Column(name = "code")
private String code;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "country")
private String country;
// @Pattern(regexp="^\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{4})$", message="Invalid phone/fax format, should be as xxx-xxx-xxxx")//if the field contains phone or fax number consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
@Column(name = "phone")
private String phone;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "website")
private String website;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "image")
private String image;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Lob
@Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
@Column(name = "description")
private String description;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "add_user")
private int addUser;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "last_mod")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date lastMod;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "credit_limit")
private double creditLimit;
// @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;




public Breweries() {
}

public Breweries(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Breweries(Integer id, String name, String address1, String address2, String city, String state, String code, String country, String phone, String website, String image, String description, int addUser, Date lastMod, double creditLimit, String email) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.address1 = address1;
    this.address2 = address2;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.code = code;
    this.country = country;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.website = website;
    this.image = image;
    this.description = description;
    this.addUser = addUser;
    this.lastMod = lastMod;
    this.creditLimit = creditLimit;
    this.email = email;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress1() {
    return address1;
}

public void setAddress1(String address1) {
    this.address1 = address1;
}

public String getAddress2() {
    return address2;
}

public void setAddress2(String address2) {
    this.address2 = address2;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getWebsite() {
    return website;
}

public void setWebsite(String website) {
    this.website = website;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public int getAddUser() {
    return addUser;
}

public void setAddUser(int addUser) {
    this.addUser = addUser;
}

public Date getLastMod() {
    return lastMod;
}

public void setLastMod(Date lastMod) {
    this.lastMod = lastMod;
}

public double getCreditLimit() {
    return creditLimit;
}

public void setCreditLimit(double creditLimit) {
    this.creditLimit = creditLimit;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Breweries)) {
        return false;
    }
    Breweries other = (Breweries) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "lit.sd4.model.Breweries[ id=" + id + " ]";
}
```

The code for the BreweriesGeocode.java is:

```
package brewery.src.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author Brendan
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "breweries_geocode")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "BreweriesGeocode.findAll", query = "SELECT b FROM BreweriesGeocode b"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "BreweriesGeocode.findById", query = "SELECT b FROM BreweriesGeocode b WHERE b.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "BreweriesGeocode.findByBreweryId", query = "SELECT b FROM BreweriesGeocode b WHERE b.breweryId = :breweryId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "BreweriesGeocode.findByLatitude", query = "SELECT b FROM BreweriesGeocode b WHERE b.latitude = :latitude"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "BreweriesGeocode.findByLongitude", query = "SELECT b FROM BreweriesGeocode b WHERE b.longitude = :longitude")})
public class BreweriesGeocode implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "brewery_id")
private int breweryId;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "latitude")
private float latitude;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "longitude")
private float longitude;

public BreweriesGeocode() {
}

public BreweriesGeocode(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public BreweriesGeocode(Integer id, int breweryId, float latitude, float longitude) {
    this.id = id;
    this.breweryId = breweryId;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getBreweryId() {
    return breweryId;
}

public void setBreweryId(int breweryId) {
    this.breweryId = breweryId;
}

public float getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(float latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public float getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(float longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof BreweriesGeocode)) {
        return false;
    }
    BreweriesGeocode other = (BreweriesGeocode) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "brewery.src.model.BreweriesGeocode[ id=" + id + " ]";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the latitude and longitude fields on the form.
2. Create a DTO class, which contains old (`Breweries`) and new (`BreweriesGeocode`) fields
3. Update the `/addBrewery` method by changing of an input param to that DTO.
4. Map the DTO to `Breweries` and `BreweriesGeocode` entities and store them.